# If dd zero does not "format" my disk what should i do?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, dd, badblocks

I got a softbricked/hardbricked 1TB WD Passport HDD which happened when transfering a suspected 11GB PS3 game file from my mac.As for repairing, My mac cannot do anything with the HDD, so I'm trying to solve it using linux machine.
by running : `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb > badsectors.txt`
I got an unlimited number of lines in badsectors.txt, which takes a very long time.
I tried `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` , it completed after awhile left me an unpartitioned space. I thought it fixed already, I formatted it and tried to see if it has any problem, but unfortunatelly, it still blinking like forever and never mount. scanning it from thunar file manager will freeze the thunar, and gparted will scan forever, the only way to determine if its connected is using `sudo fdisk -l`

so what should I do?
zero out the bad blocks one by one using `dd seek` command?

Comment: Have a look at the SMART information, see `man smartctl` on Linux. Very likely something is broken you cannot solve by writing zeros (which only helps to reallocate bad sectors, if you've a few of them, anyway).

Comment: this is the output: https://justpaste.it/67lfi

Comment: i tried `sudo smartctl -d sat,12 --all /dev/sdb` and here is the output https://justpaste.it/84pwm slightly different from before, now it says SMART is supported.

Comment: Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.

Comment: looks like dying to me, the drive itself is only 2yo since i bought it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the highest possible read error rate:

```
 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   001   001   051    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 72289
```

which means there's some hardware defect somewhere.

This drive is dead.

Comment: i see, so its 100% broken. phew... what a waste, maybe i shouldve bought a ssd instead of hdd, lol.

Comment: @AhiungLim there's this thing with SSDs: they often die totally unexpectedly while data recovery becomes totally impossible (even reading it). HDDs normally have a period of time when they start failing, you can see that and then you'll be able to take action.