# is my thumbdrive dead?

Tags: usb-drive, readonly, badblocks

I got a 16GB Sandisk thumbdrive which was "locked" recently while transfering data, and now I can't do anything to the drive, only able to read the remain data. below here are some attempt to get the infos as much as I could.

1. attempt to zeroing the drive

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb     
   dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
   ```
2. attempt to get the SMART info:

   ```
   sudo smartctl -d scsi --all /dev/sdb
   smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
   Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

   === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
   Vendor:               SanDisk
   Product:              Cruzer Blade
   Revision:             1.27
   Compliance:           SPC-4
   User Capacity:        15.744.892.928 bytes [15,7 GB]
   Logical block size:   512 bytes
   Serial number:        20044317411DEF60D95B
   Device type:          disk
   Local Time is:        Wed Aug 19 14:42:34 2020 WIB
   SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
   SMART support is:     Enabled
   Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

   === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
   SMART Health Status: OK
   Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
   Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

   Error Counter logging not supported

   Device does not support Self Test logging
   ```
3. attempt to scan the `badblocks`:

   ```
   sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb > badsectors.txt
   Checking blocks 0 to 15375871
   Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
   Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
   ```
4. attempt to remove the READ-ONLY flag:

   ```
   sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

   /dev/sdb:
   setting readonly to 0 (off)
   readonly      =  0 (off)
   ```

What should I do?

FYI: this thumbdrive's misfortune happened the same time together along my HDD, which was posted on [If dd zero does not "format" my disk what should i do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605195/if-dd-zero-does-not-format-my-disk-what-should-i-do) ,and the HDD is sentenced dead for good.

Comment: How is it mounted? Include the output of `mount` in your question by editing

Comment: it is mounted automatically, like a normal flashdisk would do, whats inside is files with "locked" icon, which can be copied to internal storage, but we cannot put anything new on the external, including deleting what is inside the external drive.

Comment: [This is](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/) my bookmark that I keep on-hand just for these types of questions. The answer is, unfortunately, that your drive is dead - but the link has tons of stuff you can still try, including the `mkusb` method.

Comment: @KGIII yeah, thats the fact, i just cant believe that we couldnt do anything to it since it can be read by system just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for some unknown reason, a thumbdrive can't get into this state... the device itself, not the filesystem.

You can try this to reset the flag:

```
hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

Something similar happened to me: a USB thumbdrive suddenly turned "read-only".
Unfortunately `hdparm` and other methods all failed, so i considered the device dead.

Comment: ah, i remember trying this command too, to remove the read-only flag. but, even with the flag removed, it is still in read-only state...

Comment: What the SanDisk claim about this matter is that `the read-only is there to protect the file from further damage` or somewhat like that. But, I dont want to give up just that, there must be someway to unlock the drive.